# zabbix agent tries to speak with server

Tags: linux, zabbix

I want to create a zabbix proxy and a zabbix agent and setup the agent to speak through the proxy.I have created docker containers for this (zabbix-proxy and zabbix-agent).

proxy.conf:

```
Server=192.10.30.58  # address of server
ServerPort=10051
Hostname=DFS
```

agent.conf:

```
Server=ZabbixProxy  # the zabbix-proxy container name
ListenPort=10050
Hostname=Agent
```

I have created also in zabbix :

A proxy named DFS.

A host named DFS and 192.10.30.3:10051

A host named Agent and 192.18.0.4:10050 (an internal IP where the agent is running)

I can see data from Monitoring-> Latest Data for both the proxy and the agent.

So, it work.

But, in my log I can see that for the agent it gives me:

```
INFO success: zabbix-agentd entered RUNNIG state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)


failed to accept an incoming connection: connection from "192.10.30.58" rejected, allowed hosts: "ZabbixProxy"
```

(The 192.10.30.3:10051  is the external ip of proxy)

It seems that the agent tries to speak with the server also but I don't know why.

If in agent.conf instead of `ZabbixProxy` (the name of the zabbix proxy container) I put the address of proxy 192.10.30.3 , then I still have the same errors and also I can't get Latest data for the agent.

---

I I use `ServerActive=ZabbixProxy`  or `ServerActive=192.10.30.3:10051`, I am receiving:

```
...
INFO spawned: 'zabbix-agentd' with pid 51
2017-04-12 16:37:55,916 INFO exited: zabbix-agentd (exit status 1; not expected)
2017-04-12 16:37:57,928 INFO spawned: 'zabbix-agentd' with pid 52
2017-04-12 16:37:57,988 INFO exited: zabbix-agentd (exit status 1; not expected)
2017-04-12 16:38:01,001 INFO spawned: 'zabbix-agentd' with pid 53
2017-04-12 16:38:01,061 INFO exited: zabbix-agentd (exit status 1; not expected)
2017-04-12 16:38:02,063 INFO gave up: zabbix-agentd entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly
```

and of course now the agent doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

Parameter `Server` is for passive items - incoming connections to the agent. Agent connects to the server (or proxy) based on the parameter `ServerActive`, which seems to be misconfigured in your case.

Comment: Hi, I am a bit confused right now.So, Agent only uses the ServerActive?Anyway, I updated my post.It doesn't work at all like this.Am I missing something?Thank you.

Comment: Hmm.It seems it needed to add the server's ip also , not only the zabbix proxy ip into the Server field!

Comment: No, you should only have either the server, or the proxy listed in `ServerActive`. Agent failing to start up seems like a weird problem - you should try to start it manually and see what the error message is.

Comment: What about [this](https://www.zabbix.com/forum/showthread.php?t=12277)answer?It says to use `Zabbix server and Zabbix proxy IP's`.Just, note that I am not using ServerActive at all, only Server field.

Comment: Let's dig into your original problem description. Who has the IP of 192.10.30.58? Does "ZabbixProxy" reverse-resolve to that IP?

Comment: This is the address of the server.The address of proxy is 192.10.30.3.But , as I told you above, using only the Server field but putting both addresses (server and proxy) works.

Comment: Normally, you should not include them both, as that indicates misconfiguration. In this case, it looks like the server is connecting directly to the agent. The host is probably not assigned to be monitored by the proxy.

Comment: The agent is assigned to be monitored by the proxy if you mean that.